# How to code a drag-lock using RxJS?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

A drag-lock interaction starts with a first double-click, followed by some mouse moves, and ends with a second double-click. It is a variant of the drag-and-drop.

I want to code this interaction in RxJS, but the big problem I face is that the same event (double-click) starts and ends the interaction (a problem we do not have while coding a drag-and-drop).

How to implement a drag-lock using RxJS?
I want to subscribe to the first-click, to all the moves, and the final double-click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/MXUtPzH9iD40VjVxLBwB?p=preview

Lets define an event - DragLockEvent which consists of type "DragLockEventType" which could be either 'initialClick', 'move' or 'finalClick', and the mouse move event, in case it is of type 'move'.

Now let's create an observable which will emit these events: dragLock$.

Inside the observable there's a flag - "dragging", indicating whether or not we are in the middle of dragging.

Now we need to listen to double click events, and for each such event we need to toggle the dragging flag, and to emit the matching event.

Then, in case we are in dragging mode, we start listening to mouse move events and report them, until we have another double click.

```
type DragLockEventType = 'initialClick' | 'move' | 'finalClick';

interface DragLockEvent {
    type: DragLockEventType;
    moveEvent?: MouseEvent;
}

const dragLock$: Observable<DragLockEvent> = Observable.create((observer: Observer<DragLockEvent>) => {
    let dragging = false;

    const doubleClick$ = fromEvent(document.documentElement, 'dblclick')
        .pipe(takeWhile(() => !observer.closed));
    const mouseMove$ = fromEvent(document.documentElement, 'mousemove')
        .pipe(takeWhile(() => !observer.closed));

    doubleClick$
        .pipe(
            tap(() => {
                dragging = !dragging;
                if (dragging) observer.next({ type: 'initialClick' });
                else observer.next({ type: 'finalClick' });
            }),
            filter(() => dragging),
            switchMap(() => mouseMove$.pipe(takeUntil(doubleClick$)))
        )
        .subscribe((e: MouseEvent) => observer.next({ type: 'move', moveEvent: e }))
});
```

Comment: Great! Two questions:

1/ Is there any technical reason for using `pipe`, or you just want to handle pure functions?

2/ I ported the code to _RxJava_ (that does not provide any `pipe`), and I had to add `.share()` at the end of the statement `const doubleClick$ = ...`. Why `share()` is not necessary in your code? Maybe it is related to the use of `pipe`.

Comment: 1. pipe is a rather new concept in rxjs. instead of adding operators to the Observable.prototype by calling "import 'rxjs/add/operator/...'" you use the operator by using .pipe(), so you do not pollute the Observable.prototype. 
Here are some links about this concept:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-understanding-lettable-operators-fe74dda186d3
https://blog.hackages.io/rxjs-5-5-piping-all-the-things-9d469d1b3f44

Comment: 2. what the share operator does is causing all subscribers to subscribe to the same "instance" of the observable, meaning that instead of creating a new Observable for each subscription, all the subscriptions share the same observable. 
If there is more than 1 subscriber to the doubleClick$ observable, a share() operator would be necessary to sync all subscribers.